# Difference between the 2 passport.authenticate methods

Tags: node.js, passport.js

It is the  same login route.
Just 2 different approaches.

First route

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local',{session:false}),async (req,res) => { 
  console.log("\n\n\n ------------------------222222")
        console.log(req.user);
    });
```

and the request object has the user & is displayed.

Whereas in the second route

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', async (err, user, info) =>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("\n\n\n ------------------------")
        console.log(req.user); //undefined
    if(user){
      // it works here 
    }
    else{
      res.status(422).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

`console.log(req.user);` shows undefined.
but the user has the user details fetched from the mongo db.

Can someone explain me please.

Comment: First print console.log(req.body), then try to fetch req.body.user

Comment: It only logs the body { email: 'loremipsun@gmail.com', password: 'loremipsum' } which is provided in the request

Comment: then you need to assign first user details to any var to fetch req.user, In req.user assign user details so that you can fetch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second function, you get the user in the `user` key. However, you ll have to add it to `req` object. It can be done like this

```
if(user){
  // it works here 
  req.user = user;
}
```

In the first case, it is already added to the `req` object since it has already executed `passport.authenticate` before getting into the next async function.
If you print the `req.user` after the if else, it will give you the exact details.